# Choosing lambda, blocks and alpha for collaborative filtering

Tags: apache-spark, collaborative-filtering

I am experimenting with a recommender engine that uses online transactions as "ratings" with a fixed rating of 1.0.

`// trainImplicit(RDD<Rating> ratings, int rank, int iterations, double lambda, int blocks, double alpha, long seed)
model = ALS.trainImplicit(ratings, 10, 10, 0.01, -1, 1.0, seed)`

Rank and iterations can be found by testing, whatever combinations yields the lowest RMSE, but I don't know which observations would hint towards changing the values for lambda, blocks and alpha.

Would I also just try a number of values see which combination yields the best results?

Comment: What do you mean by "which observations would hint towards changing the values of lambda" ? And yes you can perform grid search cross validation to find which hyper-parameter gives you the best evaluation metrics.

Comment: What I saw is that my results varied a lot when using a random seed value (the default System.nanoTime()). Would this hint towards overfitting where any of these parameters can help? If a grid search is what the pro's would do, that's alright!

Comment: lambda is another hyperparameter you can tune. It is indeed used to prevent overfitting.